# How can I get last index of slidesperview?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I'm working with SwiperJS and currently showing some thumbnails for my slider with the prop `slidesPerView={5}`

However, how can I get the last and first index of the thumbnails that are actually showing?

Tried looking at the docs but it doesn't say anything about that. I know there is something called `onActiveIndexChange` but that just says whatever image is focused and showing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onActiveIndexChange` or `onTouchEnd`, depending on your use case on the thumbnail swiper, *not* the main slide swiper. You can get the first and last index of the visible thumbnails from the `visibleSlidesIndexes` property available on both the functions

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-react-thumbs-gallery-forked-bsnovm?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A19%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A68%2C%22startColumn%22%3A9%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A68%7D%5D) is a sample codebox.